# Whats the need of ')' in statment

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
System.out.println(i+"\t\t\t"+(i*i)+"\t\t\t"(i*i*i));  
                                        ^
error:')'expected
```

Comment: none, you´re simply missing a `+` for the concatination before the second paranthesis

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a **"+"**

Try this :

```
 System.out.println(i+"\t\t\t"+(i*i)+"\t\t\t"+(i*i*i));
```

Comment: To explain (I suppose)  the downvoter, you destroyed the line by removing `*` ;)